In Altium Designer 23, is there a way to set a clearance rule that is measured from the center of a TH pad to the copper of any SMD pad?
The need for this rule is to have a proper clearance for a selective solder nozzle. When a selective solder machine puts solder on a TH pin, the nozzle is at the center of the pad. I need to make sure there is enough clearance around the TH pad that matches the diameter of the nozzle.

Because Altium's clearance rules seem to only be based on copper to copper, I basically need a variable copper clearance based on a mathematical function.

This question is related to a previous question of mine: Altium Designer 23 DRC Rule Creation: How do I set a special clearance rule for a TH Pad to SMD pad?

Given the range of THT pad sizes in the design, is the SS nozzle and associated solder wash area, really so precisely defined that a edge-to-edge rule would not suffice?  Even if so: is such a range of sizes used that it would really be onerous to use a set of pad-size-ranged queries to approximate it? (Pondering the last few designs I've worked on, I think all of them would be accurately covered with perhaps 1-3 such rules.)

@TimWilliams, of course individual rules can be made to fit every scenario, however, on an off chance, say you add a part that has almost the same sized TH pads as another parts TH pads (maybe 2mm vs 2.05mm), you may not realize there is not a rule set for it so a generic rule to govern the same clearance concept from a center point would be less likely to cause clearance issues in the future. Considering selective solder machines are used commonly, one would think that Altium would add a special manufacturing rule set for it such as the Hole Size or Board Outline Clearance, etc.
